# Within a SOA Service can I bind a process to an XSD complex type as opposed to an element

Tags: xml, oop, xsd, bpel, oracle-soa

We are creating an enterprise level XSD structure to handle common elements within our system. As an example we have the following complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:attribute name="First" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="Last" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Off of this complex type we derive the following two elements:

```
<xs:element name="Employee">
    <xs:extension base="Person" />
    <xs:attribute name="SSN" type="xs:string" />
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:extension base="Person" />
    <xs:attribute name="CustomerID" type="xs:integer" />
</xs:element>
```

We would like to have a SOA Service which would be bound to the Complex Type of "Person" rather than a concrete implementation like "Employee" or "Customer". Essentially we would like to handle SOA inputs as polymorphic objects rather than concrete implementations.

Is there a way to bind a BPEL WSDL to an abstract type as opposed to a concrete element?

Answer (score 0):

### XML Schema complexType Element

**abstract**
Optional. Specifies whether the complex type can be used in an instance document. True indicates that an element cannot use this complex type directly but must use a complex type derived from this complex type. Default is false. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp)

### XML Schema extension Element

The extension element extends an existing simpleType or complexType element. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="yourNameSpace"
    xmlns="yourNameSpace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="Person" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="First" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Last" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Employee">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Person">
                <xs:attribute name="SSN" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Customer">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Person">
                <xs:attribute name="CustomerID" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

---

> Oracle SOA web service it doesn't recognize the abstract type as a
>   usable type.

### XML Schema any Element

The any element enables the author to extend the XML document with elements not specified by the schema. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_any.asp)

see namespace attribute to add restrictions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="yourNameSpace"
    xmlns="yourNameSpace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Person" type="Person"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" namespace="##targetNamespace"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="First" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Last" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Employee">
        <xs:attribute name="SSN" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Customer">
        <xs:attribute name="CustomerID" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've tried declaring a complex type as abstract and it works from a purely XSD specification standpoint but when I attempt to use it as a reference for an Oracle SOA web service it doesn't recognize the abstract type as a usable type. I should have phrased my question to be more centered around the idea of using this abstract type as the parameter to an Oracle SOA web service.

Comment: you could use <xs:any> within Person to wrap a hierarchy, more or less like SOAP style wrapped. above an example

Comment: I tried and the SOA client still won't recognize the complex type "Person" as an available (albeit abstract) type. I have a suspicion that the BPEL process will only recognize a concrete type (element) that has been implemented based on "Person". This may be a limitation of SOA that we will have to compensate for.

Comment: Is strange for the second solution "person" not is abstract

Comment: It seems that the SOA BPEL service won't recognize "ComplexType" by itself as a valid definition for a WSDL. Only "element" seems to be a valid construct.

Comment: Have you tried to add <xs:element name="Person" type="Person"/> into last schema?